# sitio no seguro certificado SSL

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, certificado-ssl, windows-server

Buen día, tengo un inconveniente con mi pagina, instale mi sitio en un VPS y agregue un certificado SSL y funciona pero antes de entrar sale el mensaje "SITIO NO SEGURO" alguien sabe a que se debe? mi sitio es [**este**](https://www.emplenio.com)

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que pude ver el certificado que estás usando es "auto-firmado", es decir que no fue extendido por una CA (Certificate Authority) confiable.

Los navegadores web ya vienen con un certificado de las principales CA y por eso cuando entrás en un sitio, cualquier certificado instalado firmado por una de estas CA es reconocido y si no hay otros problemas muestra el candado verde.

Como los navegadores no tienen un certificado que matchea el que vos hiciste, entonces desconocen el certificado de tu sitio y levantan la alerta.

Para corregir el problema necesitás comprar un certificado de una CA confiable.
O, si es solo para probar, podés hacer que el navegador haga una excepción y lo de como  válido. (La excepción tiene que ser dada en cada navegador)

EDICION I: Buscá Lets Encrypt, ellos extienden certificados gratis con vigencia de 90 días.

Comment: de hecho tengo uno de comodo, pero no puedo hacerlo quedar, al instalarlo en mi maquina virtual este lo borra

Comment: Que servidor web estas usando? Por otro lado el servidor virtual lo manejas vos o es un hosting?

Answer (score 1):

por lo que vi ya tienes un certificado ssl, lo importante es configurarlo bien. Muchos te recomendarán usal Lets Encrypt, pero yo te recomiendo usar un certificado "Comodo".

El como se registran todos estos certificados depende de tu máquina virtual, por lo que es muy difícil a ciencia cierta decirte qué estás haciendo mal si es que ya compraste uno.

Comment: De hecho mi maquina virtual viene con uno, pero tambien adquiri uno de comodo, solo que al instalarlo en mi VPS, cuando quiero seleccionarlo no aparece,se borra